# ImportError with bob.core: OSError: bob/core/libbob_core.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost9iostreams4zlib8deflatedE

Tags: python, c++, shared-libraries, python-bob

Python bob.core import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bob/core/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    bob.extension.load_bob_library('bob.core', __file__)
  File "/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bob/extension/__init__.py", line 244, in load_bob_library
    ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(full_libname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 440, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 362, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bob/core/libbob_core.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost9iostreams4zlib8deflatedE
```

I have got no idea how  to resolve this. All efforts for help are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having a C++ ABI compatibility issue introduced in gcc 5. Try exporting these variables either to 0 or 1. One of them might work depending on your system:

```
export CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"
export CXXFLAGS="${CXXFLAGS} -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"
```

You need to export theses before doing pip installation of any packages (bob.extension, bob.blitz).
Although as I said in the bob-devel mailing list. It is better to use our conda installation: https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/install

Comment: I tried exporting the variables but it still didn't work. But by using conda I have successfully installed all bob packages and they work perfectly.   Thank you for your help